# D3.js V4 : How to create X axis with time and %H:%M:%S format

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to create a chart with X axis that shows timely progress of a trade with %H:%M:%S format.

I have tried following code but it shows years only. The seconds are very important to show on the x axis. I  know timeParse needs to be used but I am not sure how to leverage it. I have searched a lot online but no examples.

```
  // Add X axis

  var parseDate=d3.timeParse("%H:%M:%S")
  var x = d3.scaleTime()  
  .domain([new Date(0,0,0), new Date (12,59,59)])
  .range([ 0, width ]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need the following:

The desired scale.

```
var x = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain([new Date(1554236172000), new Date(1554754572000)])
  .range([0, width]);
```

The axis with the correct format and the number of desired ticks, you may want to use `.ticks(d3.timeMinute.every(desiredMinutesToHandle));` for a better display of your data.

```
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
  .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%H:%M:%S"))
  .ticks(50);
```

Finally append your axis to your svg with certain transformations to have a nice look

```
svg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "x axis")
 .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
 .call(xAxis)
 .selectAll("text")
 .attr("y", -5)
 .attr("x", 30)
 .attr("transform", "rotate(90)")
```

[Plunkr with working code](https://plnkr.co/edit/1SFK5HjSDb7vMaTizuLS?p=preview)

Comment: perfect. Thank you!

Comment: What does new Date(1554236172000) do ?

Comment: It just creates a Date object, in this case I used a Date constructor with a Unix timestamp. You can find more info here  [JavaScript Date MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Syntax)